# Understanding Dynamic memory keyword New

Tags: c#, new-operator

I was reading the documentation for the new operator, and it is used to create new objects on the heap and invoke constructors. What does this definition mean in layman's term because I am a young programmer I would appreciate if the answers be explained in very simple terms or phrases.

The particular code of line I came across new is doing the example from an internet source completing a c# tutorial.

```
var newNumber = new StringBuilder();
```

So, I am asking for simple examples that break down what the new operator, and also if you can tell me what the line of code does would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine we are talking about sandwiches. I like subs; you like rolls. We are talking about something we know exists, but isn't in front of us. We're talking about those *types* of sandwiches.

Of course, after all this talk, we get hungry and go to a deli. I say I like subs and want a *new instance* of that type of sandwich - one I can hold, see and thankfully, eat.

`new` operates on a type and returns a brand-new instance of that type, distinct from all others. Just like my sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new instance of an object, and placed it on the heap. Doing this also launches the constructor of the object, which you can modify to your liking. For example, assume I have a class Person, I could create the constructor:

```
 public Person(String name)
 {
    // do something with name
 }
```

This would let other classes implementing Person know that when creating a new instance out of Person, they need to give a String as a parameter.

They would then call

```
 var newPerson = new Person("John");
```

The new keyword basically creates a concrete instance of the 'blueprint' you have defined elsewhere. Thus in the above code, newPerson would be an actual object, which is based on the blueprint in the "Person" class.

With dynamic is meant that you don't have to do the allocation of the objects on the heap yourself. This is delegated, so you don't have to worry about where in memory your actual object is. (Unlike in some other programming languages, which give you more control).

This means that as a programmer, you don't know where to find your object but you don't care, as long as you can use it. :)

Comment: Everytime another object wants to use to object of person they have to create a new instance of it?

Comment: If it's an object you will use several times, you will keep it in a variable, of course. Tipically a variable of the class. If that object can be used by other objects, then you make that variable public. This is an extremely brief and simple explanation. You should start reading a programming book for a proper understanding!